# Can I do this vectored text search in R without a for loop?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two data sets. One has a lengthy combinations of text keys attached to identifying data:

```
set.seed(123)
library(tidyverse)

id <- paste0("V", sample((1000:9999), size = 5))
text <- c("ARROW", "ARROWHEAD", "OTHERARROW", "OTHER", "HEADOTHER")

df <- tibble(id, text)
df

  id    text      
  <chr> <chr>     
1 V3588 ARROW     
2 V8093 ARROWHEAD 
3 V4679 OTHERARROW
4 V8944 OTHER     
5 V9460 HEADOTHER
```

The other looks up those keys and assigns them shorter values:

```
original <- c("ARROW", "HEAD", "OTHER")
revised <- c("A", "H", "O")

lookup <- tibble(original, revised)
lookup

  original revised
  <chr>    <chr>  
1 ARROW    A      
2 HEAD     H      
3 OTHER    O
```

My desired output is to make `df1`, a data frame that replaces `text` with a combination of `revised` codes:

```
correctText <- c("A", "AH", "AO", "O", "HO")

df1 <- tibble(id, correctText)
df1

  id    correctText
  <chr> <chr>      
1 V3588 A          
2 V8093 AH         
3 V4679 AO         
4 V8944 O          
5 V9460 HO
```

What is the *most efficient* way to do this (base R or dplyr only)? Right now I'm doing it with a `for` loop, but it's too slow for the Shiny app where I want to implement it.

Comment: The `for` statement I'm currently parsing it with lists it as `AO`. Assume that order does not matter.

Comment: can you please check my solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_replace` with a `named` vector

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
    mutate(text = str_replace_all(text, set_names(revised, original)))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  id    text 
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 V3462 A    
#2 V3510 AH   
#3 V9717 OA   
#4 V3985 O    
#5 V2841 HO
```

`stringr` functions are based on `stringi` and should be very efficient

Answer (score 1):

With base R only (and `dplyr`, since you use a tibble, so I threw `mutate` in as well), you could use this function:

```
multisub <- function(target, output, string) {
  replacement.list <- apply(cbind(target, output), 1, as.list)
  mygsub <- function(l, x) gsub(pattern = l[1], replacement = l[2], x, perl=TRUE)
  Reduce(mygsub, replacement.list, init = string, right = TRUE)
}

df %>% mutate(text = multisub(original, revised, text))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   id    text 
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 V3462 A    
#> 2 V3510 AH   
#> 3 V9717 OA   
#> 4 V3985 O    
#> 5 V2841 HO

# base R oly:
data.frame(id=id, text = multisub(original, revised, text), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Performance-wise it is pretty competitive with the `stringr` solution.

Comment: This code is great for my example, but I had trouble applying it to my real-life code. Thank you though!